# Angular Toaster not working in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typescript1.5

I have downloaded angular-toaster.d.ts file from nuget and implemented a notification service no error but it is not working

```
export class notificationService {

    constructor(private toaster: ngtoaster.IToasterService) {
        debugger;                

        // this.toaster.toast.timeout = 3000;
        // this.toaster.toast.type = EnergyTechApp.Entity.Constants.info;
        // this.toaster.toast.showCloseButton = true;
    }

    displaySuccess(message: string) {                
        debugger;

        this.toaster.success(message); /// not working  Not displaying anything
        this.toaster.success("", "", 122, ""); // this is a overload     
    }
}
```

I didn't exactly know what to send in overload , overload in d.ts file is

```
success(title?:string, 
        body?:string, 
        timeout?:number, 
        bodyOutputType?:string, 
        clickHandler?:EventListener,
        toasterId?:number): void
```

What is eventHandler and what I have to pass to make toaster work?

Comment: is the toast coming up? Are there any console errors

Comment: toast is not coming up and no errors in console even. :-(

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

Whether the toaster works or doesn't, doesn't have anything to do with TypeScript. In the end, it's the JavaScript that should be running correctly. So TypeScript has nothing to do with the problem, unless of course, you're having compile errors?

I think the main issue here, is that you don't construct the toaster service properly. It gets injected into the constructor of your server, but I don't see `$inject`. Assuming this is an angular service, you should use angular dependency injection. My guess would be that this.toaster is undefined, which would explain why it's not working. But you should see some console errors. Try something like this:

```
static $inject = ["toaster"];
constructor(private toaster: ngtoaster.IToasterService) {

}
```

If things still don't work, make sure the scripts are loaded and that you added the toaster module as a dependency:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['toaster', 'ngAnimate'])
```

Lastly, clickHandler allows you to execute some code when the user clicks the toaster. But it's an optional argument, you don't really need it. Things should be working fine by just using this:

```
this.toaster.success("hello");
```

Comment: Implemented the same , but not working :-( and I think $inject is used to avoid minification level issues